# want to convert json string to json object containing xml

Tags: java

I want to convert json string to json object. I am using the following method.

```
public List convertJsonToObject(String json) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
  List myObjects = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference>() {}); 
  return myObjects; 
}
```

The problem is that my json string has XML content in it, which gives error because of double quotes. What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure your json string is valid? Can you post it here?

Comment: Please post the JSON! Otherwise it’s almost impossible to give concrete help.

Comment: Here is the json
[{"orderNo":"20139429260","sapRequest":"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" s..","customerResponse":"<?xml version="1.0" e....]}

Comment: That is not valid JSON. You should generate your JSON properly.

Comment: What is wrong in this?
{"orderNo":"20139429260","sapRequest":"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" s..","customerResponse":"<?xml version="1.0" e....}

there are just three values

Comment: That is not valid JSON. You should generate your JSON properly. I don't know how to make it more clear than that. [Paste it here](https://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: That is what I am trying to say here.
The JSON get invalidated due to the double quotes in the xml.
That is what I am trying to find a solution for.

Comment: So when you generate the JSON, generate it properly. Use a library to do it. And if you are using a library to generate it, switch to a different library that does not generate invalid JSON.

Comment: Your comments are quite generic.
Could you please be more specific.
I am making this JSON without any library

Comment: If you do not want to invest the time in understanding why your JSON is invalid (or how to fix it), you should not be generating it by hand. You should be using a library. My comments are generic because I could tell you how to fix this one specific problem (you need to escape the `"` in your XML content with `\"`) but there will undoubtedly be more problems. [Use. A. Library.](https://json.org/)

Comment: I know that I need to escape the " , but the XML is not in my hand.

Comment: If you were using a JSON library, the library would take care of the appropriate escaping for you. It doesn't matter that you are getting the XML from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert a valid json. 
I reformatted your incomplete JSON a bit. Please try this one.
You need to escape some characters. The `"` character needs to be escaped.

```
[
  {
    "orderNo":"20139429260",
    "sapRequest":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" s..",
    "customerResponse":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" e....
   }
]
```

Comment: The XML comes from 3rd party.
I am just putting it as a value in my JSON.

Comment: To put it into a json you have to reformat it first to convert it into an escaped string.

Comment: 1. get the xml 2. transform the xml 3. put the transformed xml into your json

Comment: Thanks I used StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml/StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml.

Comment: yeah sure - whatever you like.